# SQL return more than 1 value query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with updating OR INSERTING a column based on condition. I want to be able to insert a variable if the reference number has not existed before in the table and if it exists then it should update. My question is that the @checklistscore is returning more than one row. When I did select @checklistscore it is giving the same error. How can I resolve this

```
  SET XACT_ABORT ON; 
DECLARE @TRANSACTION VARCHAR(20) = 'EXAMPLE';
BEGIN TRAN @TRANSACTION
DECLARE @checklistscore INT;

SET @checklistscore = (SELECT 
      CASE 
        WHEN CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN D_CHECK_LIST.EVALUATION  NOT IN (0,1) THEN EVALUATION ELSE NULL END) AS FLOAT) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE
        (
          CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN D_CHECK_LIST.EVALUATION  IN (2, 3, 50001, 50003, 50004, 50005, 50006, 50020, 50027, 50028) THEN EVALUATION ELSE NULL END) AS FLOAT)
            /
            CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN D_CHECK_LIST.EVALUATION  NOT IN (0,1) THEN EVALUATION ELSE NULL END) AS FLOAT)
        ) * 100 

    END  FROM DB.D_CHECK_LIST   INNER JOIN DB.D_ENERGY_REFERENCE ON  D_CHECK_LIST.ID =D_ENERGY_REFERENCE.ID AND D_ENERGY_REFERENCE.REFERENCE = 19051
    GROUP BY D_CHECK_LIST.ID)

BEGIN

IF
    /* CHECKLIST TO UPDATE*/
    (EXISTS     
        (SELECT *
        FROM    DB.D_ENERGY_REFERENCE D_ENERGY_REFERENCE
                ,DB.D_CHECK_LIST D_CHECK_LIST
        WHERE   D_ENERGY_REFERENCE.ID = D_CHECK_LIST.ID
        AND     D_ENERGY_REFERENCE.REFERENCE = 19051


        )
)

BEGIN   
UPDATE DB.D_ENERGY_REFERENCE 
SET D_ENERGY_REFERENCE.VALUE_INTEGER =  @checklistscore 
FROM DB.D_ENERGY_REFERENCE
INNER JOIN DB.D_CHECK_LIST D_CHECK_LIST ON D_ENERGY_REFERENCE.ID = D_CHECK_LIST.ID
WHERE  D_ENERGY_REFERENCE.REFERENCE = 19051



END

ELSE 

BEGIN 

INSERT INTO DB.D_ENERGY_REFERENCE(ID, REFERENCE_NO, REFERENCE,VALUE_INTEGER)
(SELECT ID, 
                (SELECT  ISNULL(MAX(REFERENCE_NO), 0) + 1 FROM DB.D_ENERGY_REFERENCE),
                19051,  @checklistscore 

FROM DB.D_ENERGY_REFERENCE D_ENERGY_REFERENCE

GROUP BY D_ENERGY_REFERENCE.ID
)

END
```

Comment: I did not see a question in your information.  You might get more help if you clearly articulate what it is that you need assistance with.

Comment: @DeadZone, the question has been edited. But the checklistscore is returning more than one value and how can I used it in the SQL statement without this error.cheers

Comment: Grouping by D_CHECK_LIST.ID means that you will get 1 row returned for every unique D_CHECK_LIST.ID value in the D_CHECK_LIST table.  If you only want a single result (which it looks like you do, because you're putting it into a variable) then you need to rewrite the query.  You'll need to elaborate more on what @CheckListScore is supposed to contain.  From reading your query, I cannot infer what it is supposed to be.

Comment: No I am looking for each row not single result. It means that eg for ID 10 will have is own score. If that is the case should I ignore using the variable in the insert or update statement

Comment: I think what you'll need to do is replace your variable with a temporary table.  The temporary table can store 1 row for every ID.  Then, your second half of your script will want to join with the temporary table using ID as the join condition and update every row, that way.

Comment: Cheers. I have changed the code

Answer (score 1):

I think what you'll need to do is replace your variable with a temporary table. The temporary table can store 1 row for every ID. Then, your second half of your script will want to join with the temporary table using ID as the join condition and update every row, that way.

(Reposted my comment as a suggested answer.)